# PDO inserting and updating

Tags: mysql, pdo

So after my recent topic i learned about PDO. I'm trying my best to understand it and thats working to. But now the problem is that my new pdo script wont insert and update if exists in database. Now i'm asking it here because i'm a starter in PDO and i'm trying my best on it.

Now this is the code i'm using.

```
$db->prepare(
'INSERT INTO track (`rsname`, `overallranknow`, `overalllevelnow`, `overallxpnow` )' .
'VALUES (' .$name. '. ' .$Overalln. ', ' .$Overall[1]. ', ' .$Overall2. ') '. 
'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' .
    "rsname = ' .$name. '"  .
    "overallranknow = ' .$Overalln. ' " .
    "overalllevelnow = ' .$Overall[1].' " .
    "overallxpnow = ' .$Overall2. ' " 
);
```

The code is like doing nothing now

-it is not inserting into the database.

-it is not updating into the database.

Also my database connect file is this

```
<?php
$config['db'] = array(

'host'          => 'localhost',
'username'      => '',
'password'      => '',
'dbname'        => ''
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['db'] ['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['db'] ['dbname'], $config['db'] ['username'], $config['db'] ['password'] );
```

Maybe i'm posting mutch question's here and i know but i want to learn it.

~Kev (bad english = sorry)

Comment: It's great that you're using PDO, but you **cannot** write SQL code this way without introducing severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Your query should look like `INSERT INTO track (...) VALUES (:name, :Overalln, :Overall1, Overall2)...` and then you bind values to those placeholders during the `execute` call: `execute(array('name' => $name, 'Overalln' => $Overalln, 'Overall1' => $Overall[1], 'Overall2' => $Overall2))`.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your comment! But what do u mean with "execute"? could u maybe place it the code that i has posted?

Comment: Also i like to update the table if it exist is that possible to?

Comment: Normally you `prepare` a statement, then you `execute` it or nothing happens.

Comment: @Kev30 look for `bindValue()` inside of `PDOStatement class` in the PDO manual. Everything will be clearer

Comment: @tadman I'm getting the following error :


Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in  on line 146

Line 146:

$sth->execute(array('name' => $name, 'Overalln' => $Overalln, 'Overall1' => $Overall[1], 'Overall2' => $Overall[2]));

Comment: As @STTLCU suggests, does using the `bindValue` method work better?

Comment: @tadman What do u mean with that :x? looked up in google and i dont really know what it means

Comment: @Kev30 look at that here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php

Comment: @tadman

$sth->bindValue(':name', $name);
$sth->bindValue(':Overalln', $Overalln);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall1', $Overall[1]);
$sth->bindValue(':Overall2', $Overall2);
$sth->execute();

It says its the execute line is wrong or something

Comment: Help :x? I dont know what to do

Comment: @Kev30 open a new question with your new problem. the comments aren't made for discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prepared statement needs to be executed in order to actually hit the database.

You should adjust it to look more like this:

```
$sth = $db->prepare(
  'INSERT INTO track (`rsname`, `overallranknow`, `overalllevelnow`, `overallxpnow` )' .
  'VALUES (:name, :Overalln, :Overall1, :Overall2) '. 
  'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' .
    "rsname = :name"  .
    "overallranknow = :Overalln" .
    "overalllevelnow = :Overall1" .
    "overallxpnow = :Overall2" 
);

$sth->execute(array('name' => $name, 'Overalln' => $Overalln, 'Overall1' => $Overall[1], 'Overall2' => $Overall[2]));
```

Comment: This works, but for reference and for novice users i'd add a mention of `bindValue` which imho makes the code easier to read and to debug. Once you do so, you'll have my +1

Comment: Also, i'd write the query as a single string rather a concatenation of many strings.

Comment: Constructing the string is a matter of preference, so I've just preserved what @Kev30 had there. Execute with named arguments isn't bad, it should be pretty clear here what's going on. `bindValue` tends to be quite verbose and doesn't add much in the way of clarity.